# Can't access router/modem web interface

Tags: networking

I changed the port on my router/modem Comtrend Model VR-3033 from port 80 to 8001 and now the login to the router wont load the page completely.  It almost loads the first page but stops and wont load any other pages.  Internet still works I was trying to clear up port 80 so I could host my website off my computer to a domain.  Ive did this before no problem but now for some reason the website would load my routers homepage and not the apache page.  But now I cant access the modem to change the ports back and reconfigure what I changed because my server still wont load on my domain.  Any advice Thanks

Comment: If you don't have that much investment in the configuration of the router.. just reset the thing?

Answer (score 2):

I would reset to factory defaults and set it up again. I do this routinely for modems / routers to ensure a clean setup.

Their manual says in section 3­7 System Reset that you can reset to factory defaults. It also says there is a Restore to Factory Default tool and you may need to try that.

You should be on the phone with your ISP so they can reconnect you when you reset it.

[Comm Trend Modem Manual](https://us.comtrend.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Manual_WR-5882.pdf)

> Reset / WPS Reset the router to factory default settings (clear all
> settings) or start the WPS function. Press this button and hold for 10
> seconds to restore all settings to factory defaults, and press this
> button for less than 5 seconds to start the WPS function.

Comment: Problem is the modem configured to my internet provider and I've reset it before a while back and they had to bring out a new router because I reset it.  I saved a backup of the router before I changed the settings but don't know if that would work to reset it and upload it if it has the settings to my ISP in it or not?  I don't want to loose internet for a few days and have to pay for a new modem again.

Comment: Ask your ISP if you can reset it while you are on the telephone line with them. They should be able to connect you up while you wait. That should work.  I added that note in my answer.

Comment: There is no way to connect to it other than the HTTP interface?  I know when I changed that port there was a list of other ports being used like SSH and FTP so on.  I've tried SSH with no luck but I'm connected through a Google WiFi which is connected to my modem/router. I've tried off the desktop connecting straight to the router with no luck I get more of the web ui on my laptop.

Comment: The ISP may be able to reset if for you. I would certainly call them.